# OAuth Sign in Error when trying to use Google Provider with Next.js

Tags: next.js, google-oauth

I'm getting the following error when trying to sign in " signin?error=OAuthSignin "
I'm also receiving a " try signing in with a different account " message on my site

The console displays the following:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXouZ.png)

I have set the Google ID like this:

```
providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        })
    ],
```

and the following is in my .env file:

```
GOOGLE_ID = string.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = string
```

Haven't been able to figure out by surfing the web and any guidance is appreciated. Thank you for your time

Tried surround my GOOGLE_ID value in brackets, like:

GOOGLE_ID = "stuff"

Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out. I had incorrectly configured my setup with MongoDB and once I fixed it, the issues with google sign in cleared up. Here's what I did exactly:

1. Fixed the MONGODB_URI in .env

Switched GOOGLE_ID to GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID in the env and when calling for it with

```
clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
```